# Offline geocoding for web on Windows systems

Tags: openstreetmap, data, geocoding, nominatim, hong-kong

I'm developing an WebGIS in Windows development platform that cannot use Internet and need to deal with maps and positioning. The place where I need to geocode to is HongKong.

Download OpenStreetMap's Nomination seems to be a good solution to access map information offline. But only Ubuntu/Debian and CentOS system are identified in its installation instructions. Windows is not one of these.

I use PostgreSQL and PostGIS as my database, and the TIGER dataset in PostGIS, which is a product of the US Census Bureau. This was created to support the US Constitution's requirement for a decennial census to support redistricting in the US House of Representatives. Their mandate only covers US states, commonwealths, territories, and possessions. And Hong Kong is not one of these.

I have downloaded Geonames data from http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/, but these data are very incomplete.

Then I downloaded OSM data from http://download.geofabrik.de/asia.html. But its SHP file looks like it has no information about coordinates and zip code, and I don't know how to open or process the other two format files.

I would like to obtain Hong Kong data which contains coordinates and zip code,  where can I get in addition to OSM and Geonames? Or who can tell me how to install the nomination to my Windows 10 system?

If there are other better methods can also tell me.

Comment: If Hong Kong has open data then try researching at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**T**opologically **I**ntegrated **G**eographic **E**ncoding and **R**eferencing (TIGER)](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger.html) dataset is a product of the US Census Bureau. It was created to support the US Constitution's requirement for a decennial census to support redistricting in the US House of Representatives. Their mandate only covers US states, commonwealths, territories, and possessions.  As Hong Kong is not one of these, you'll need to search [elsewhere](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -1):

You could locally deploy the Photon geocoder by Komoot: https://github.com/komoot/photon and get geocode results via get request from your application.